# GraphDB workbench won't load .gz complressed .brf files from Mac

Tags: macos, rdf, graphdb

I am using GraphDB 9.1.1, and I am speaking about my experiences with the web-based Workbench.

I have a folder of `.brf` binary RDF files on my Mac. Some are `.zip` compressed, some are `.gz` compressed, and some are uncompressed.

From Chrome or Firefox under macOS Catalina 10.15.7:
When I click on *Import* (in the Workbench's left-hand menu) -> *RDF* -> *Upload RDF Files*, I can upload the `.brf.zip` files and the uncompressed files, but not the `.brf.gz` files. They are greyed out.

[image: greyed-out .brf.gz files in GraphDB import dialog]

Loading one of the `.brf.gz` files from Chrome in Windows 10 is successful. With some little effort, I could do the whole thing from Windows or Ubuntu Linux, but my team hasn't planned on switching to a newer GraphDB version yet.

The *Upload RDF Files* hover-over help says

> The supported RDF formats are ... .brf ..., as well as their .gz versions and .zip archives

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is some MacOS issue that won't accept the .gz variants of file extensions (e.g. .brf.gz, .ttl.gz etc) even though they are correctly listed by GraphDB as accepted for the file dialog. There is no workaround in Safari but there is one in Chrome and Firefox:

1. Click the Options button in the lower left corner.
2. Choose "All files" instead of "Customised Files".

Please see the attached screenshots.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks. Your solution does make the .brf.gz files available in FireFox I also tried in Chrome 87.0.4280.67. The .brf.gz files were still gray after switching the "all files". It seems like I had to do a few additional mouse clicks before the .brf.gz files became clickable, like closing the options box, sorting the file listing, slowly clicking multiple times on a single .brf.gz file.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the filename should present format or:

if you have file with name movieDB.gz, it won't be available for import, but if the filename is movieDB.brf.gz import will be available and successful.

Comment: Thanks, but that is not what I have found. Please see the screenshot I have attached to my question.